# Importing project form from Eclispe ADT to Studio throws error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am importing an Eclipse ADT project I received from a colleague into Android Studio 1.4. I have selected import as a non android studio project and when importing it is throwing the below error. 
OS: Mac 10.10.3

```
* Project a_final:/Users/John/AndroidStudioProjects/a_final/project.properties:
Library reference ../appcompat_v7_29 could not be found
Path is /Users/John/AndroidStudioProjects/a_final/../appcompat_v7_29 which resolves to /Users/John/AndroidStudioProjects/appcompat_v7_29
```

I added Android support Library to Studio already hoping that would resolve the issue but the issue still prevails. I am unable to import project at all.

Comment: ask your friend to give you the gradle build you can generate it easily from File > Export > Android > Generate Gradle Build files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what caused it but you can fix it by editing the project.properties file for the eclipse project. You will see a reference to this rogue compatibility library. It might look like

```
android.library.reference.4=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

Delete those lines and import the project, then add the support library again into your grade build manually.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Comment: This helped the import. But import showed the below errors? Would this be related? I haven't added the compile code yet.      Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: Added the compile line and that line shows in red and compile generates a lot of error like one below:  Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.

Comment: I was able to fix this. The error was that my compileSDKVersion was not matching the one in the compile code above.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply in time. Glad it was at least some help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Delete all dependencies in project.properties file. Then try import the project as Android project itself.

Comment: Will try but will this convert the structure to Studio structure?

Answer (score 0):

why are you importing your project as a non android project, I think it will work if you import  it  as a android project.

Comment: I meant non Android Studio project(as in Eclipse ADT, Gradle etc. ) and Importing as an Android Studio project was showing a different file structure and throwing appcompat error in styles.xml